# Adding magento menu to custom page

Tags: magento

I have a magento custom page which is the homepage for our site - the guy before me however for some reason did not add the main menu to this page. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We hope that your question, when answered, will be as useful as possible to other readers, so it's not necessary to post about your own experience with WordPress or to say 'thanks'. Please try to post what you have done so helpers know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

The way i work with menus in Magento is:

First, i create a custom block, from the cms menu, in that block i add the li:

```
<li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
```

Then in your template, edit the following file: app/desing/frontend/yourtheme/default/page/html/topmenu.phtml

you will see: `<?php echo $_menu ?>` before it add:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('yourblockname')->toHtml() ?>
```

And then you will be able to manage the menu option from your admin panel in your custom block.

I hope this help.